# Yarn version is wrong when using using nvm

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nvm, yarn-workspaces

```
Node Version
01-Nov-2021 15:43:30    v12.16.1
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    /opt/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.7
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── @angular/cli@12.2.7
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── appcenter-cli@2.10.2
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── bower@1.8.12
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── newman-reporter-html@1.0.5
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── newman@5.3.0
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── npm@7.24.1
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── purple-hats@
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── serverless@2.60.1
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── test_proj@
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    ├── typescript@4.4.3
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    └── yarn@1.22.15
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    which yarn
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    /opt/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/yarn
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    yarn -v
01-Nov-2021 15:43:33    3.1.0
```

Even though the yarn installed globally is 1.22.15, When I do yarn -v it's showing 3.1.0. Any reason why? I don't have .yarnrc on m project either.

Comment: I did upgrade from 1.22.5 to 1.22.15, but it keeps showing the original version for some reason. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I faced this issue on our bamboo, Turns out it's the `/home/bamboo/.yarnrc.yml` causing this issue.